# Maestro detalle API .NET CORE 3.1, Angular 9 y SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, angular9

Estoy desarrolando mi proyecto final para graduarme de la Tecnología en programación.

Es una tienda online, y hasta el momento se desarrollaron ya los crud de las entidades, proveedor, producto, categoria producto, estado producto, compra.

Actualmente estoy tratando de desarrollar el modulo de detalle compra-producto, pero realmente **no encuentro cómo implementarlo**, ya que la api trae los productos con su categoría a través del Json, la idea es que tengo un formulario que está compuesto por compra, compra tiene IdCompra, FechaCompra y IdProveedor, y el formulario de detalle compra que tiene el IdCompra, IdCompraProducto, CantidadProducto, Costo, Idproducto.

La idea es que con un mini formularios se agregan productos a una tabla de compra, y cuando se de clic en el botón de guardar compra, se cree el registro en la tabla compra, se devuelva el Id Compra como foránea en el DetalleCompraProducto, se guarde el detalle compra y los productos, pero en este momento no tengo idea de como se implementaría.

Si me pueden recomendar recursos, tutoriales, o alguna info que me pueda ayudar, o me pueden dar alguna recomendación de como realizar esto, se los agradecería.

Interfaces Angular

```
  export interface CompraProducto {
  IdCompraProducto: number;
  CantidadProducto: number;
  Costo: number;
  FkidCompra: number;
  FkidProducto: number;
  }
  export interface Categoria {
  IdCategoria: number;
  NombreCategoria: string;
  DescripcionCategoria: string;
}
export interface Compra {
  IdCompra: number;
  FechaCompra: Date;
  FkidProveedor: number;
}
export interface EstadoProducto {
  IdEstadoProducto: number;
  NombreEstado: string;
  DescripcionEstado: string;
}
export interface Producto {
  IdProducto: number;
  NombreProducto: String;
  Descripcion: String;
  Precio: number;
  Cantidad: number;
  FechaVencimiento: Date;
  RutaFotoProducto: String;
  TablaNutricion: String;
  FkidCategoria: number;
  FkidEstadoProducto: number;
}
export interface Proveedor {
  Idproveedor: number;
  Identificacion: number;
  NombresProveedor: string;
  ApellidosProveedor: string;
  PaisProveedor: string;
  CiudadProveedor: string;
  EmailProveedor: string;
  TelefonoProveedor: string;
  CelularProveedor: string;
}

registrarcompra-produto.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { GestionCompraProductoService } from 'src/app/services/gestion-compra-producto.service';
import { ConfiguracionService } from 'src/app/services/configuracion.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { GestionProveedorService } from 'src/app/services/gestion-proveedor.service';
import { Proveedor } from 'src/app/models/proveedor.model';
import { GestionProductoService } from 'src/app/services/gestion-producto.service';
import { Producto } from 'src/app/models/producto.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registrar-compra-producto',
  templateUrl: './registrar-compra-producto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registrar-compra-producto.component.css']
})
export class RegistrarCompraProductoComponent implements OnInit {

  listaProveedor:Proveedor[];
  listaProducto:Producto[];

  constructor(public formBuilder:FormBuilder, public gestionCompraProductoService:GestionCompraProductoService, private configuracion:ConfiguracionService,
    private toastr:ToastrService, private gestionProveedorService:GestionProveedorService, public gestionProductoService:GestionProductoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.gestionProveedorService.listarProveedor().then((res)=> this.listaProveedor = res as Proveedor[]);
  this.gestionProductoService.listarProducto().then((res) => (this.listaProducto = res as Producto[]));
}
  onSubmit(){
    this.gestionCompraProductoService.compraProducto = this.gestionCompraProductoService.formRegistroCompraProducto.value;

    if(this.gestionCompraProductoService.compraProducto.IdCompraProducto == 0 || this.gestionCompraProductoService.compraProducto.IdCompraProducto== null)
    {
      this.guardarCompraProducto();
    }
    else{
      this.editarCompraProducto();
    }
  }
  guardarCompraProducto(){
    this.gestionCompraProductoService.guardarCompraProducto().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.gestionCompraProductoService.formRegistroCompraProducto.reset();
        this.toastr.success("Se guardó el producto exitosamente!");
        this.gestionCompraProductoService.actualizarListaCompraProducto();
      },
      err =>{
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }
  editarCompraProducto(){
    this.gestionCompraProductoService.editarCompraProducto().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.gestionCompraProductoService.formRegistroCompraProducto.reset();
        this.toastr.info("Se actualizó correctamente el producto.", "¡Actualización exitosa!");
        this.gestionCompraProductoService.actualizarListaCompraProducto();
      },
      err =>{
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }
  llenarProveedor(proveedor:Proveedor){
    this.gestionProveedorService.formRegistroProveedor.patchValue(proveedor);
  }
  llenarProducto(producto:Producto){
    this.gestionProductoService.formRegistroProducto.patchValue(producto);
  }
}

Gestion-compraproducto.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { CompraProducto } from '../models/compra-producto.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfiguracionService } from './configuracion.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GestionCompraProductoService {

  formRegistroCompraProducto = this.formBuilder.group({
  IdCompraProducto: [0],
  CantidadProducto:[""],
  Costo: [""],
  FkidCompra: [""],
  FkidProducto:[""]
  });

  compraProducto:CompraProducto;
  listaCompraProducto: CompraProducto[];

  get CantidadProducto(){
    return this.formRegistroCompraProducto.controls["CantidadProducto"];
  }
  get Costo(){
    return this.formRegistroCompraProducto.controls["Costo"];
  }
  get FkidCompra(){
    return this.formRegistroCompraProducto.controls["FkidCompra"];
  }
  get FkidProducto(){
    return this.formRegistroCompraProducto.controls["FkidProducto"];
  }

  constructor(public formBuilder:FormBuilder, private http:HttpClient, private configuracion:ConfiguracionService) { }

  guardarCompraProducto(){
    if(this.compraProducto.IdCompraProducto==null)
    {
      this.compraProducto.IdCompraProducto=0;
    }
      return this.http.post(this.configuracion.rootURL + '/CompraProducto', this.compraProducto)
  }

  actualizarListaCompraProducto(){
    this.http.get(this.configuracion.rootURL + '/CompraProducto')
    .toPromise()
    .then(res=>
      this.listaCompraProducto = res as CompraProducto[])
  }

  eliminarCompraProducto(id){
    return this.http.delete(this.configuracion.rootURL + '/CompraProducto/' + id)
  }

  editarCompraProducto(){
    return this.http.put(this.configuracion.rootURL + '/CompraProducto/' + this.compraProducto.IdCompraProducto, this.compraProducto)
  }
}

registrarcompraproducto.html

<div class="container-fluid">
  <form [formGroup]="this.gestionCompraProductoService.formRegistroCompraProducto" class="form-group" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="hidden" name="IdCompraProducto" formControlName="IdCompraProducto">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="IdCompra" formControlName="IdCompra" placeholder="Número compra">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="FechaCompra" formControlName="FechaCompra" placeholder="Fecha Compra">
          <select class="custom-select" name="FkidProveedor" formControlName="FkidProveedor">
            <option disabled selected value> --Seleccione Proveedor-- </option>
            <option *ngFor="let Proveedor of listaProveedor" [value]="Proveedor.Idproveedor">{{Proveedor.NombresProveedor}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="FkidCompra" formControlName="FkidCompra" placeholder="Compra">
            <select class="custom-select" name="FkidProducto" formControlName="FkidProducto">
              <option disabled selected value> --Seleccione Producto-- </option>
              <option *ngFor="let producto of listaProducto" [value]="producto.IdProducto">{{producto.NombreProducto}}</option>
            </select>
            <input class="form-control" name="CantidadProducto" formControlName="CantidadProducto" placeholder="Cantidad Producto">
            <input class="form-control" name="Costo" formControlName="Costo" placeholder="Precio costo">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar </button>
        </div>

      <!-- Tabla donde se muestran los productos que se agregan a la compra -->
      <div class="col bg-light" style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-borderless">
              <thead class="table-dark">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" class="col-3">Producto</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="col-3">Costo</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="col-3">Cantidad</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="col-3">Total</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" [disabled]="this.gestionCompraProductoService.formRegistroCompraProducto.invalid"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Lectura extremadamente obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, lo que sucede es que no buscaba solución a parte del código sino más cómo la idea global de como resolver la situación. Pero de verdad aprecio el aporte

Comment: Ese es un problema, dado que ideas globales son ideas sueltas se alejan de los lineamientos del sitio. Dicho de otro modo, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y es inexistente una respuesta "perfecta" debido a que existe un "depende" de cómo se implemente... Que no te sorprenda si terminan cerrando tu pregunta. Te sugiero que respondas algunas preguntas más y entres a la sala de chat donde hablamos de cosas así y todo fresh~

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, entiendo

Comment: Vale, lo que puede ser posible es que intentes resolverlo y que pongas límites donde la pregunta puede tener una respuesta en particular, dejando de lado las N posibles soluciones, espero me deje entender :D